# Making second parameter of model (ModelBuilder) to be optional?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder

I have built a model to create file structure for a feature class input, basically, it creates a database, then a dataset, selects by attribute, exports data, names feature class, puts it all in the same place with the same structure and naming convention, no matter the user or machine.

There will always be two inputs, the feature class being compared, and the feature class it's being compared to. This is the main branch. The two inputs have exports based upon a single attribute requirement, and two feature classes are exported and placed in one database.

Then, there may or may not be 2-5 other sources that also need to be compared.

The next part is already a separate branch in the model, connected only by the same folder for the next databases to be saved. I think I might need an if/else, that is, if: a user selects a feature class in the 3rd (and beyond) parameter box, then the separate branch(es) of the tool runs, else: they don't then only the main branch runs, and the tool completes without error and only a single database/feature class is created. Otherwise, the number of databases outputted will match the number of 'needs to be compared' feature class inputs.

But my Python skills are virtually non-existent, if that is the way I need to go.

Right now, the one needs to recycle the 'needs to be compared' feature class input then delete the resulting database to accommodate the extra lines in the tool interface. It works, and since stuff needs to happen now, no one is complaining. But this is not practical, obviously.

*Separate databases are required in a future step, so that cannot be changed.
*I'm trying to be vague on explaining only my process and outcome needs on purpose.
*I cannot post screen shots. This model is not my property.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to make parameters optional because you need to have variability with the data. You can right-click in the model area and go to model properties. There is a parameters tab where you will be able to change the required or optional setting. If you cannot change it from required to optional, go back into the model and delete the "connect link", go back into the parameters tab and they should be able to be switched to optional, and then re-connect the link. This worked for me.